# How to check if variable empty in Drools Templates

Tags: templates, drools

I'm using Drools templates to generate Rules from a spreadsheet.
I have some problems with empty cell. 
Does anybody know how to check if a cell or the variable is empty?
This is the template:

```
template header
pid
department
maxAmount
storeId

package X.X.X

declare MaxAmountStore
    amount : Integer    
    storeId : String
end

template "FOO"
rule "MaxAmountStore_@{row.rowNumber}"
        when
            Product(pid == "@{pid}")
            Product(departmentId == "@{department}")
        then
            System.out.println("New MaxAmountStore: @{maxAmount} (store: @{storeId})");
            insert( new MaxAmountStore(@{maxAmount}, "@{storeId}"));
    end
end
```

Is it possible to have an empty storeId?

Comment: Your rule doesn't make sense. The consequence doesn't depend on anything matched in the condition. The condition might match for two different Product objects, but also for the same. Replacing the parameter `@{storeId}` with and empty string is of course possible, but this would even make less sense.

Comment: Ok, hopefully now it's getting clearer:
when
 Product(pid == "@{pid}" or departmentId == "@{department}")
then
          
 insert( new MaxAmountStore(@{maxAmount}, "@{storeId}", "@{pid}"));

The question is what if the department column is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this: if there's nothing in the cell, you don't care about the departmentId value and want to fire the rule based on pid alone.

```
template "FOO"
rule "MaxAmountStore_@{row.rowNumber}"
when
    Product( pid == "@{pid}"&& 
             ("" == "@{department}" || departmentId == "@{department}") )
then
    ...
end
```